# Trim different characters from beginning and end of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, trim

In a database running MySQL I have data in a column that contains text that begins and ends with a paragraph tag and I am trying to remove them during the select statement

```
<p>Some Text</p>
```

I understand the TRIM statement can remove specific characters from the start, end or both of the string so

```
TRIM('x' FROM xSometextx) as trimmed
```

This will remove the x from the beginning and end of the string, but I cannot find away to TRIM the beginning and end characters if they are different. For example is it possible to remove the leading `<p>` and trailing `</p>` in the select statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) with the specifier `LEADING` and `TRAILING` to remove the `<p>` tag:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '</p>' FROM TRIM(LEADING '<p>' FROM '<p>Test</p>'))
```

Since MySQL 8.0 you can also use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to remove the `<p>` tag, like the `TRIM` above:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<p>Test</p>', '^\<p\>|\<\/p\>$', '')
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9ff13fc943c6f789adf7193e515ae2d)